# Sample Variance and Population Variance for Ungrouped data

Tags: machine-learning, variance

A study of the effect of smoking on sleep patterns is conducted. The measure observed is the time, in minutes, that it takes to fall asleep. These data are obtained:

**Smokers:** $69.3, 56.0, 22.1, 47.6, 53.2, 48.1, 52.7, 34.4, 60.2, 43.8, 23.2, 13.8$

**Non-Smokers:** $28.6, 25.1, 26.4, 34.9, 28.8, 28.4, 38.5, 30.2, 30.6, 31.8, 41.6, 21.1, 36.0, 37.9, 13.9$

I have to find `Variance` for both of the given groups

### Question

As we know there are two types of Variance `sample variance` and other is `population Variance`, Which type of Variance I should use to find the variance of above(given) ungrouped data and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given data for two samples, so I suppose you are to find *sample* variances:
$S = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar X)^2.$

Before conducting formal tests, it is customary to look at various numerical
summaries of the data:  Here are some numerical summaries from R statistical
software (thanks for providing data in a convenient format):

```
smoke = c(69.3,56.0,22.1,47.6,53.2,48.1,52.7,34.4,60.2,43.8,23.2,13.8)
summary(smoke);  length(smoke);  var(smoke);  sd(smoke)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  13.80   31.60   47.85   43.70   53.90   69.30 
[1] 12         # sample size
[1] 286.5491   # sample variance
[1] 16.92776   # sample standard deviation

non_s = c(28.6,25.1,26.4,34.9,28.8,28.4,38.5,30.2,30.6,31.8,41.6,
          21.1,36.0,37.9,13.9)
summary(non_s);  length(non_s);  var(non_s);  sd(non_s)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  13.90   27.40   30.20   30.25   35.45   41.60 
[1] 15
[1] 50.94695
[1] 7.137713
```

It seems that non-smokers fall asleep more readily. We can graph the data in various
ways to get an overview.  Stripcharts, show exact positions of the data values in each sample. The following style of stripchart is suitable for data with no ties. (Smokers are at the bottom)

```
stripchart(list(smoke, non_s), pch = "|")
```

[image]

Boxplots use the quantiles `1st Qu` and `3rd Qu` to make the ends of the boxes.
The medians are at the line within the box. The maximum and minimum values are also
plotted for each sample. (The detached value at left for a non-smoker denotes a
subject who fell asleep unusually quickly--compared with other non-smokers.)

```
 boxplot(smoke, non_s, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

I don't know whether you are just starting your course or whether this is a review
question. The sample mean 30.25 for non-smokers seems quite a bit smaller than the sample mean
43.70 for smokers. At some point in your course, I guess you will learn to do a
formal statistical test to see whether non-smokers fall asleep *significantly* more
quickly than smokers, in a statistical sense. For such a test, you will need sample sizes, means, and variances, as shown above.

Here is output from R statistical
software for one such test. I don't want to overwhelm you prematurely with technical details, so I'll just comment on one part of the output.
Because the P-value (about 0.02) is smaller than $0.05 = 5\%$ many statisticians
would say that the difference in sample means is statistically significant. (Roughly speaking, it would very unlikely to get *sample* means so far apart, if the *population* means are not really different.)

```
t.test(smoke, non_s)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  smoke and non_s
t = 2.5747, df = 14.127, p-value = 0.02191
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
   2.254755 24.638578
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 43.70000  30.25333
```